# On scroll change opacity of header?

Tags: jquery, scroll, opacity

Im so new to JQuery and im sure the answer is super basic. But if someone can point me in the right direction that would be great. I just want the opacity of my header to change from 0 to 1 as the user scrolls past 400 pixels. HELP? www.HULU.com has a perfect example.

```
<code>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
                $('.header').css("background", "#000");
            } else {
                $('.header').css("background", "transparent");
            }
        });
        });
</script>
</code>
```

Comment: Seems to be working as expected, but you're just setting the background, any text or child elements will still show, so you should probably set the opacity or display properties instead ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CWf2A/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this one:

> Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SEH5M/

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <div id="background"></div>
    <div id="labels">
        labels here
    </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index:3;
}

body{
    margin:0px;
}
.header #background, .header #labels
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.header #labels{
    background-color:transperent;
}

.header #background{
    background-color:yellow;
    display:none;
}


.content{
    width:100%;
    height:5000px;
    background-color:green;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 400) {
        $( ".header #background" ).fadeIn();
    } else {
        console.log('there');
        $( ".header #background" ).fadeOut();
    }
});
```