# Creating Opacity Header

Tags: html, css, header, opacity

I want to have an opacity header just like this, so when I'm scrolling down there will appear a fixed header with a black background. I had made for wordpress but now I want to make it for bootstrap but it doesn't work.

I have tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441360/on-scroll-change-opacity-of-header) as well, because this one used to work for the wordpress website but when I try it myself now it will not work.

I load the script just by using this, because it is just in the js map that is in the same place as my about.html.

```
<script src="js/header.js"></script>
```

The HTML

```
<header id="header">
  <div id="logo"><img src="./images/logo.png" /></div>
    <nav class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </nav>

</header>
```

The CSS

```
#header {
    height: 80px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    /*background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);*/
}

    #header.scrolled {
        opacity: 1; 
        background: #000;
        color: #fff;
        transition: all 1s ease;   
    }
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
      $('header').addClass('scrolled');
    } else {
      $('header').removeClass('scrolled');
    };
  });
});
```

[Example of not working](http://larsdejonge.nl/bootstrap/about.html)

I would just like to have the class added with the opacity with the 1 second fade. Or maybe a different solution on how to fix it. Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Are you loading jQuery before your JS-file?

Comment: Move this JS declaration just before body tag ends. And check that you're loading jQuery before.

Comment: You have a javascript error. (check your console)

And don't forget to add an opacity value to your header without the .scrolled class.

Comment: You should put the `transition` declaration in the `#header` selector, otherwise you won't have a transition when the class gets removed.

Comment: Thanks for the help girls/guys! I fixed it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It runs fine, you just need to move your JS to the bottom of the body, and ensure you're loading jQuery first. You can also add your transition to `#header` rather than `#header.scrolled`: this way it fades nicely when you scroll back up. See the demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(window).scroll(function() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 10) {
      $('header').addClass('scrolled');
    } else {
      $('header').removeClass('scrolled');
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#header {
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#header.scrolled {
  opacity: 1;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
.menu li {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
}
body {
  background: grey;
  min-height: 1000px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <img src="http://larsdejonge.nl/bootstrap/images/logo.png" />
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="selected"><a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Work</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have an error in the browser console and that error is because you are first placing your .js file before the file that jquery. Always place the jquery file before any .js file or js code that contains jquery functions.